# How to simulate returning to a ViewController that has not been shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an iOS application with a login screen. Once the user logs in, I use `presentViewController` to go to the main screen of the application. If the user logs out from the main screen, I `dismiss` the current (main) view controller to return to the login screen. This works fine and uses the standard animations for "present modally".

Now I want to modify this so that if the user is logged in already, the login screen is skipped. So in my application delegate I do the following (pseudo-code)

```
if (user logged in)
   presentViewController(mainVC)
else
   presentViewController(loginVC)
```

Question: If the user was already logged in and I show the main view controller directly, I cannot "dismiss" it anymore to return the login view controller (as this has never been shown). How can I then "simulate" returning to the login VC?

In Android, something similar can be achieved by manually manually building a "back stack" of activities (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal). Is there something equivalent to this in iOS ?

Comment: If it's not necessary to present MainVC after login. Suggestion to do set `rootViewController` for that. and at the time of logout you can change to rootViewController as LoginVC. And if it's necessary to present viewController then you have to check LoginVC in navigation stack or not ?. If not then again you have to set LoginVC as rootViewController. My personal suggestion go with setting of rootViewController if it's fit to your requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this approach and/or give an example?

Comment: Are you using Objective C or Swift ?

Comment: Any of them would be fine; I just want to understand the overall concept.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check at application Launching. User logged in or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


if isUserLoggedIn {
        //Set Main ViewController
        self.window?.showAuthenticationVC

    } else {
        //Optional.. But you can set here Logic VC
        self.window?.showMainController()
    }
    return true
}
```

`isUserLoggedIn` Flag that manage user loggedIn or Not. You can store that value in `UserDefaults`.

Manage to rootViewController for loggedIn and loggedOff User.

```
extension UIWindow {



 func showAuthenticationVC() {

        self.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let authenticationVC : LoginController = LoginController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authenticationVC)
        self.rootViewController = navigationController

    }

    func showMainController() {
        self.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let authenticationVC : MainController = MainController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authenticationVC)
        self.rootViewController = navigationController
    }

}
```

And at time of login action. Set `showMainController()` using AppDelegate `window`. same of at the time of logout call `showAuthenticationVC()` using  `window` property of AppDelegate.

Hope it's Help to you!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this type of problem several times. The way I handle it is I use a dummy VC at the start of the app naming it StartupVC. In the StartupVC I add the logic to check if user is logged in or not. If user is logged in I send it to the home screen. If not I present the login screen.

Now, when user logs out, I pop the view controllers up to the StartupVC. In the startup VC, I put the login check login in `viewWillAppear` method, so as soon as the StartupVC is shown again, the user is taken to login screen.

To make the transition smooth, you can turn off the animations when navigating back to login after logout.

Comment: In the StartupVC you mention that the logic check is done in viewWillAppear. But from what I have seen you cannot present a VC from there because the StartupVC is not visible (added to the hierarchy) yet -- you would need to do it in viewDidAppear. And then there is a "glitch" because the StartupVC can be briefly visible while the "next" VC is shown. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Startupvc doesn't need to be visible. I set the ui of startupvc same as the launch storyboard in this way user doesn't recognize it.

Comment: My point is that if you try to present the "next" VC from StartupVC.viewWillAppear, that will fail if the StartupVC has not been added to the hierarchy yet. Otherwise I may be missing something. Do you have a working example of this ?